# сайт на vue и нейронная сеть

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, backend, искусственный-интеллект

у меня нейронка написанная на питоне. Я хочу создать сайт на фреймворке vue с использованием этой нейронки. Как её можно прикрепить? Это должно считаться на бекэнде или использовать какой то тронслятор кода?

Answer (score 2):

Каков вопрос....

Отвечаю по пунктам.

1.*"Это должно считаться на бекэнде"* -  Смотря что имеется ввиду под "это". Если обученная модель -  то она может подключаться и на бекэнде и на фронтенде. Если сумеете. (см. п.3).

2.*"Как её можно прикрепить?"*  -  как и любой другой сторонний скрипт, с передачей ему параметров и получением от него результата и последующем их отсылом клиенту.

3.*"использовать какой то **тронслятор** кода"*  - Тут я задумался, а что вообще вы имели ввиду. Если то, что для исполнения любого скрипта написанного на Python необходим его интерпретатор -  то да, его таки придется использовать. Впрочем, тут возможны варианты, но о них - я так понимаю -  пока говорить рано.

4.Причем тут тег "искусственный-интеллект"?